# remove_action conditionally for Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, hooks

By default, my theme is showing an author box below my posts. I am using a custom post type, and would like to remove this author box only on this post type. Here is how the theme is calling the author box:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'woo_author', 10 );

if ( ! function_exists( 'woo_author' ) ) {
function woo_author () {
    // Author box single post page
    if ( is_single() && get_option( 'woo_disable_post_author' ) != 'true' ) { add_action( 'woo_post_inside_after', 'woo_author_box', 10 ); }
    // Author box author page
    if ( is_author() ) { add_action( 'woo_loop_before', 'woo_author_box', 10 ); }
} // End woo_author()
}
```

Here is the function I have tried to remove the post author box from the `wpseo_locations` single posts, but it is not working:

```
add_action('init', 'kiwi_remove_post_author_box'); 

function kiwi_remove_post_author_box () {
    if (is_singular('wpseo_locations')  ) {
        remove_action( 'woo_post_inside_after', 'woo_author_box', 9 );
    }  
}
```

I have also tried:

```
add_action('init', 'kiwi_remove_post_author_box'); 

function kiwi_remove_post_author_box () {
    if ( 'wpseo_locations' == get_post_type() ) {
        remove_action( 'woo_post_inside_after', 'woo_author_box', 9 );
    }  
}
```

I cannot seem to get that box to go away. I know that there is a check box in the theme options panel that will make it go away globally, but I want it removed only for this post type. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the actions are added with priority of 10, but you try to remove actions with priority 99?

Comment: @Milo - typo. Just made the edits. Priority 9 does not work.

Comment: they should be 10, to match the priority they were added on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query variable only can be accessed after `wp_query` has been called. In you call, the `get_post_type()` function is actually returning an empty value. It should be working, if you change the hook to something which fires after wp_query is called.
So, You should use -

```
add_action('wp', 'kiwi_remove_post_author_box');
```

OR

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'kiwi_remove_post_author_box');
```

Also, hooks can removed with the same priority value the have been added on.
So final code it would be -

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'kiwi_remove_post_author_box');
function kiwi_remove_post_author_box()
{
    if( is_singular('wpseo_locations') )
        remove_action( 'woo_post_inside_after', 'woo_author_box', 10 );
}
```

Comment: Thank you and @Milo for the clarification on priority. Removing the action on the wp_head worked, however, I had to change the remove_action inside the function. Will post the final code.

Comment: Yes, you should be using the remove_action within you function 'kiwi_remove_post_author_box'. I will update so you can understand.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Shazzad, I was able to come up with the final code that worked.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'kiwi_remove_post_author_box'); 

function kiwi_remove_post_author_box () {
    if ( 'wpseo_locations' == get_post_type() ) {
        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'woo_author', 10 );
    }  
}
```

Notice how the remove_action has changed **inside** the function. As soon as I did this it worked. Does this mean that you cannot use hooks if they are inside another function, and being called conditionally?