# remove_action conditionally for Custom Post Type - not working

Tags: filters, genesis-theme-framework

I'm using a Genesis child theme with the 'Genesis Co-Authors Plus' which enables support for `Co-Authors Plus`

I'd like to disable the author box everywhere except for the blog.

Genesis Co-Authors Plus removes the default Genesis `genesis_do_author_box_single` and replaces it with `gcap_author_box`

So far I've got a conditional function to remove `gcap_author_box` from the custom post type `local-bite`

I tested the conditional statement with a simple echo and it is working fine. So what is wrong with the following?:

```
// Remove 'Genesis Co-Authors Plus' from custom post type
add_action('init', 'lf_remove_author_box');
function lf_remove_author_box() {
    if ( is_singular( 'local-bite' ) ): {
        remove_action( 'genesis_after_entry', 'gcap_author_box', 8 );
    }
    endif;
}
```

There is a very similar post [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126820/remove-action-conditionally-for-custom-post-type) which is helpful.

but I don't understand what I need to put in immediately after add_action - I've copied what is in the Genesis Co-Authors Plus which is `init`. I've also tried `wp`, can anyone help?

Comment: You should ask this question on the genesis support forum as support for third party themes are off topic here. Thank you

Comment: ok no worries, sorry, I just saw there is a genesis theme tag so I assumed it would be fine, feel free to delete my post if need be

Answer (score 0):

I got it working in the end by using 'template_redirect' and changing the remove_action number from 8 to 1 :)

```
// Remove 'Genesis Co-Authors Plus' author box and 'filed under' from custom post type
add_action('template_redirect', 'lf_custom_cpt_display');
function lf_custom_cpt_display() {
    if ( is_singular( 'local-bite' ) ): {
        remove_action( 'genesis_after_entry', 'gcap_author_box', 1 );
        remove_action( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'genesis_entry_footer_markup_open', 5 );
        remove_action( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'genesis_post_meta' );
        remove_action( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'genesis_entry_footer_markup_close', 15 );
    }
    endif;
}
```